# Update existing javascript object with new data recursively. Arrays elements should be merged by id

Tags: javascript, lodash, underscore.js

I've created an update object API that receives new update data of an existing document.

Let's say, I have two objects `oldData` and `newData`

```
oldData = {
    me:{
        name:{
            short:'will'
            long:'william'
        }
    },
    friends:[
        {
            id: 1,
            name:{
                short:'mike'
                long:'michael'
            },games:[]
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name:{
                short:'fred'
                long:'freddy'
            }
        },  
    ],
    favoriteGames:[
        'gta',
        'animal crossing',
        'mortal kombat'
    ],
    favoriteFood:['bacon'],
}

newData = {
    me:{
        name:{
            long:'willy'
            longer:'william'
        }
    },
    friends:[
        {
            id:3,
            name:{
                short:'max',
                long:'maxwell'
            }
        },
        {
            id:1,
            name:{
                short:'mic',
            }
        },
        
    ],
    favoriteGames:[
        'tekken'
    ]
}
```

calling `applyUpdate(oldData, newData)`should return

```
result = {
    me:{
        name:{
            short:'will',
            long:'willy',
            longer:'william'
        }
    },
    friends:[
        {
            id:3,
            name:{
                short:'max',
                long:'maxwell'
            }
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name:{
                short:'mic'
                long:'michael'
            },games:[]
        }
        
    ],
    favoriteGames:[
        'tekken'
    ],
    favoriteFood:['bacon'],

}
```

Basically, the rules for merging are:

- If a key in an object is specified with new data, it overrides the
  value of the same key in old data.
- If a key is not specified, the
  value of the same key in old data is kept.
- If the value of a key in new data is an array of objects:

  - Each object must be merged BY `id` with elements in the array of the same key in `old data`.
  - Elements not included in the arrays of `newData` are removed from the result.
  - The order of elements in the arrays of `newData` should be preserved.
- Merging must be done deeply, since nested arrays and objects of unspecified depth should be possible.

I've actually successfully implemented this with a horrendously long and ugly recursive function. But am worried about performance and readability issues. I am open to suggestions using lodash or underscore.

Thanks!

Comment: *Merging must be done deeply*, do you mean array of objects with `id`s can be nested as well?

Comment: Yes! meaning Objects with ids may have arrays with objects with ids as well.

Comment: In general, I'd recommend using Backbone's Model+Collection for intelligently updating data. In your case, Backbone.Relational would come in handy as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's hard to write this in a readable way.

```js
function customizer(oldProp, newProp) {
    if (Array.isArray(newProp)) {
        // check if `newProp` is an array of objects which has property `id`
        if (typeof newProp[0] === 'object' && newProp[0].hasOwnProperty('id')) {
            if (!Array.isArray(oldProp)) {
                return newProp;
            }

            // merge objects of 2 arrays in `oldProp` and `newProp`
            const mergedArr = [];
            for (const objNewArr of newProp) {
                const objOldArr = oldProp.find(o => o.id === objNewArr.id);
                if (objOldArr) {
                    mergedArr.push(_.merge(objOldArr, objNewArr));
                } else {
                    mergedArr.push(objNewArr);
                }
            }
            return mergedArr;
        }
        return newProp;
    }
    if (typeof newProp === 'object') {
        return _.merge(oldProp, newProp);
    }
    return newProp;
}

_.mergeWith(oldData, newData, customizer); // returns the merged object
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Had to modify it since arrays in objects in arrays (nested arrays) weren't merged. Merging also mutates source objects so cloning them seemed necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked. Thanks Duc.

```
function customizer(oldProp, newProp) {
    if (Array.isArray(newProp)) {
        if (typeof newProp[0] === 'object') {
            const mergedArr = [];
            for (const objNewArr of newProp) {
                const objOldArr = oldProp.find(o => o._id === objNewArr._id);
                if (objOldArr) {
                    mergedArr.push(_.mergeWith(_.cloneDeep(objOldArr), _.cloneDeep(objNewArr), customizer));
                } else {
                    mergedArr.push(objNewArr);
                }
            }
            return mergedArr;
        }else{
            return newProp; 
        }
    }else if (typeof newProp === 'object') {
        return _.merge(oldProp, newProp);
    }else{
        return undefined;
    }   
}
var result = _.mergeWith(_.cloneDeep(oldData), _.cloneDeep(newData), customizer); // returns the merged object
```